# Duration of short ogg files (Telegram Voice messages) not correct when loaded into Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, telegram, voice, ogg

I'm trying to read voice messages, sent by Telegram, using Python but for short voice clips (< 10 seconds), it doesn't work. It shortens the duration for some reason. It looks like it has something to do with `OGG codec`, but I'm not really sure.

See here's my code, the voice clip is about six seconds, however `pydub` reads my 6 second voiceclip as 0.06 seconds.

```
import telegram
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "./dependencies/ffmpeg-20180802-c9118d4-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.converter = "./dependencies/ffmpeg-20180802-c9118d4-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg"


bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
f = bot.get_file(file_id)
f.download('output/voiceclips/{}.ogg'.format(file_id))

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_ogg("output/voiceclips/{}.ogg".format(file_id))
print('ID: {}, which is {} seconds'.format(file_id, myaudio.duration_seconds)) 

>>> ID: ______, which is 0.06 seconds
```

When I open the file in `VLC-player`, it also states that is has 0 seconds. When I try to convert it to WAV-files using FFmpeg it reads the ogg file as 6 seconds, but writes it as 0.05-second WAV file.

```
ffmpeg -i infile.ogg outfile.wav
ffmpeg version N-91549-gc9118d4d64 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180722
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 22.100 / 58. 22.100
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 26.100 /  7. 26.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[ogg @ 0000020dd375ad40] 727 bytes of comment header remain
Input #0, ogg, from 'infile.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:06.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'outfile.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.17.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.22.100 pcm_s16le
size=       6kB time=00:00:00.05 bitrate= 873.0kbits/s speed=4.12x
video:0kB audio:6kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.354167%
```

For larger files it does the work!

Comment: Please provide a short sample input file so we can duplicate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! We used opustools, https://opus-codec.org/docs/, which did work. Now, after the environment paths are set for the download folder, opusdec infile.ogg outfile.wav does work for short voice messages

Comment: A sample file would still be appreciated in case the issue is still present in ffmpeg.